# Jquery resizable plugin, set minWidth depending on the dragging edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So I have an image, around it is a crop marker, I don't want to be able to resize the crop marker smaller than the image.

To do that I will need to set the minWidth of the crop marker which is depending on from which side the user is resizing (there is a handle everywhere: n, ne, e, se etc.)

My question is: how do achieve this? (I included an image to make my question a bit more clear)

Also, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvm6X/) that demonstrates the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ilya, can you show us what you've tried so far? It's easier for people to help you if you can show some code as a starting point. Still, the picture does help and your description is great. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey. well to be honest I didn't know where to start concerning this problem, but here's the code of the full project: http://jsfiddle.net/tvm6X/

cheers mate

Comment: +1 - The jsfiddle helps see the problem first hand, which is great! I'll add your jsfiddle to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you posted this question twice. Here is my answer from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775703/jquery-resize-plugin-min-width-depending-on-which-edge-is-being-dragged/10776001#10776001): Kind of a weird interaction, but here it is ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLw3Q/))

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        handles : 'e, n, s, w',
        resize : function(event, ui){
            switch($(this).data('resizable').axis)
            {
                case 'n':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minHeight", 75 );
                    break;
                case 's':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minHeight", 100 );
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", 150 );
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", 200 );
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, there is no need to answer reposted questions multiple times. Simply flag the repost (or vote to close when you reach 3k rep), and we'll close them accordingly. For now, I've closed the other question as the one here is somewhat more complete.

Comment: Ryan thanks for the answer. I'm sure this should get the result i want! And thanks for the tips about double posting. But let's say one of my questions gets no answers, should I just edit it then? Thanks.

Also, Ryan, you say this is a weird interaction, what would be the best way to achieve my goal. If you look at the JSfiddle example I'm sure you'll see what I'm trying to do :)