# Jquery resize plugin min width depending on which edge is being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-resizable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery resizable plugin, set minWidth depending on the dragging edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772843/jquery-resizable-plugin-set-minwidth-depending-on-the-dragging-edge)

How can i set the minWidth and height depending on which edge of the element is being dragged?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hi Ilya, just FYI, you shouldn't [double post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772843/jquery-resizable-plugin-set-minwidth-depending-on-the-dragging-edge#comment14007455_10772843). Whenever you edit your question, it gets bumped back up to the top. So when I edited your other question to include your jsfiddle, that bumped it to the top again so it's visible. Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Glad you found an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just needed an answer fast so :P But yeah i know...

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a weird interaction, but here it is ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLw3Q/))

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        handles : 'e, n, s, w',
        resize : function(event, ui){
            switch($(this).data('resizable').axis)
            {
                case 'n':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minHeight", 75 );
                    break;
                case 's':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minHeight", 100 );
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", 150 );
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", 200 );
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});​
```